# Javascript get value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, date

If I have the following code in Javascript:

```
var line0 = [["2012-07-01",1.8182],["2012-08-01",1.4000],["2012-09-01",1.7500]];
```

How can I obtain the first date, which in this case is: "2012-07-01"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for line0[0][0]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `0`-th element of the array that is the `0`-th element of `line0`, so:

```
line0[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
var date = line0[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var line0 = [["2012-07-01",1.8182],["2012-08-01",1.4000],["2012-09-01",1.7500]];
alert(line0[0][0]);
</script>
```